# Showing/hiding div onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide, show

So I have a class of div's that i want to be shown or hidden depending on a variable i get.

I have this code:

```
**HTML**

<div class="div_estado" >

    testing that
</div>

<div class="div_estado" >

    testing this
</div>

**JS**

$(document).ready(function(){
var estado= 4; //instead of 4 i have "<?php echo $_GET['estado']; ?>" but let's supose its' value is 4
        if (parseInt(estado)==5) 
        {                       
            $('.div_estado').show; // not working
        }
        else {
            $('.div_estado').hide; // not working
        }
});
```

However it doesn't work properly, can you help me solve this?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9mqT6/3/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hide` and `show` are methods, not properties. The syntax for invoking a JavaScript function requires a **set of parentheses** after the function name.

```
$('.div_estado').show();

$('.div_estado').hide();
```

[**Updated JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9mqT6/5/)

Answer (score 2):

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7qqWE/)**

You should use "show()" and not just "show".  Check the jQuery API info [here](http://api.jquery.com/show/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var estado= 4; //instead of 4 i have "<?php echo $_GET['estado']; ?>" but let's supose its' value is 4
        if (parseInt(estado)==5) 
        {                       
            $('.div_estado').show(); // not working
        }
        else {
            $('.div_estado').hide(); // not working
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting `()` . It is a function not a property. Please change it to...

```
$('.div_estado').show();

...

$('.div_estado').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are simply missing brackets, it is `show()` and `hide()`.

Answer (score 0):

### **Use CSS** to hide div

```
div.radio {
    display:none;
}
```

### **IN JS** Show div on load

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div_estado').show();
});
```